# Save user data to database after creating user in Firebase web app

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I need to save additional data in registration form like name, gender, etc.

The problem is with function which automatically signs in user:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword()
```

so when the promise is fulfilled, I call:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
   username: this.get('name'),
   ...
})
```

How do I handle situation when data are not valid? When I do something like:

```
 firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
       username: this.get('name'),
       ...
 })
 .catch(()=>{
     firebase.auth().signOut();
 })
```

the user is signed in automatically with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`and then signed out.

How do I create a user and then sign him/her in?

Comment: When you create a user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ()`, that user is automatically signed in. If you want them to remain signed in, remoe the `catch()` handler.